# Regex for returning multiple values between strings separated by new line

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using PowerShell to read output from an executable and needing to parse the output into an array. I've tried regex101 and I start to get close but not able to return everything.

```
Identity type: group
   Group type: Generic
Project scope: PartsUnlimited
 Display name: [PartsUnlimited]\Contributors
  Description: {description}

5 member(s):
  [?] test
  [A] [PartsUnlimited]\PartsUnlimited-1
  [A] [PartsUnlimited]\PartsUnlimited-2
  [?] test2
  [A] [PartsUnlimited]\PartsUnlimited 3

Member of 3 group(s):
e [A] [org]\Project Collection Valid Users
  [A] [PartsUnlimited]\Endpoint Creators
e [A] [PartsUnlimited]\Project Valid Users
```

I need returned an array of:

```
test
[PartsUnlimited]\PartsUnlimited-1
[PartsUnlimited]\PartsUnlimited-2
test2
[PartsUnlimited]\PartsUnlimited 3
```

At first I tried:

```
$pattern = "(?<=\[A|\?\])(.*)"
$matches = ([Regex]$pattern).Matches(($output -join "`n")).Value
```

But that will return also the "Member of 3 group(s):" section which I don't want.

I also can only get the first value under 5 member(s) with `(?<=member\(s\):\n).*?\n` ([?] test).

No matches are returned when I add in a positive lookahead: `(?<=member\(s\):\n).*?\n(?=Member)`.

I feel like I'm getting close, just not sure how to handle multiple `\n` and get strings in between strings if that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps (not sure if `\G` is supported in `PowerShell`).

1. The first step would be to separate the block in question with

   `^\d+\s+member.+[\r\n]
   (?:.+[\r\n])+`

   With the `multiline` and `verbose` flags, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EEWg93/4/).
2. On *this block* we then need to perform another expression such as

   `^\s+\[[^][]+\]\s+(.+)`

   Again with the `multiline` flag enabled, see [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EEWg93/2/).

---

The expressions explained:

```
^\d+\s+member.+[\r\n]     # start of the line (^), digits, 
                          # spaces, "member", anything else + newline
(?:.+[\r\n])+             # match any consecutive line that is not empty
```

The second would be

```
^\s+                      # start of the string, whitespaces
 \[[^][]+\]\s+            # [...] (anything allowed within the brackets), 
                          # whitespaces
 (.+)                     # capture the rest of the line into group 1
```

---

If `\G` was supported, you could do it in one rush:

```
(?:
    \G(?!\A)
    |
    ^\d+\s+member.+[\r\n]
)
^\s+\[[^][]*\]\s+
(.+)
[\r\n]
```

See [**a demo for the latter on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EEWg93/3/) as well.